# composer install gives errors on Gitlab CI

Tags: php, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I try to run *composer install* command on Gitlab runner. I would like to install dependencies first of all on runner. But I am getting following error. When I try on my local machine, I install all dependencies without error.

```
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install symfony/security-guard 4.1.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard 4.2.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.0-BETA3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - don't install symfony/security-guard v4.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.17 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.17].
    - Installation request for symfony/security-guard ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-guard[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.0-BETA1, v4.1.0-BETA2, v4.1.0-BETA3, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6].
```

My Gitlab CI file;

```
image: php:7.1

variables:
  ENV: master
  LABEL: latest
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
stages:
- master

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y zip unzip wget apt-transport-https curl software-properties-common gnupg2 libmcrypt-dev
- apt-get install -y make ca-certificates openssl python
- apt-get install -y libxml2-dev --no-install-recommends
- docker-php-ext-install bcmath xml mbstring
- docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
- export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
- export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
- php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
- php composer-setup.php
- php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
- mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

build:
  stage: master
  script:
  - composer install
  - cd res/deployment/
  - sh build.sh
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: My first guess is that your composer.lock file may be out of date; out of curiousity, what does your composer.json file look like?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I deleted composer.lock file and tried again, result is same. I uploaded composer.json. https://gist.github.com/yildizberkay/58fad4e16d0e29efd6f273bd5f325910

Answer (score 0):

It is related with composer version, I couldn't solve the problem exactly, but I reverted the composer version to 1.7.2 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like composer cannot resolve your conflicting dependencies as it says.
symfony/symfony:3.4.* depends on symfony/security-guard:3.4.*, (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/composer.json)  but you are requiring version 4.1.x explicitly.

Try `composer remove symfony/security-guard && composer require symfony/security-guard:3.4.*`